# Filter chain halted as :doorkeeper_authorize! rendered or redirected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, devise, doorkeeper

I am building a Rails API and am currently using doorkeeper and devise to authenticate users with the **ResourceOwnerFromCredentials** flow. All works fine however, I cannot get the authentication to work in **Rspec**.

Here is how am integrating the app in rspec:

```
    let(:app_country) { FactoryGirl.create(:app_country)}
    let(:valid_attributes) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:app_city, {:app_country_id => app_country.id}) }
    let(:valid_session) { {:format => :json} }

    let(:application) { Doorkeeper::Application.create!(:name => "App HQ dashboard", :redirect_uri => "https://localhost:3000/callback") }
    let(:hq_user) { app_country.hq_users.create!(FactoryGirl.attributes_for :hq_user) }
    let(:token) { Doorkeeper::AccessToken.create! :application_id => application.id, :resource_owner_id => hq_user.id }
```

But each time I try to test a protected action, the tests fail and I get the following output from the console:

```
Filter chain halted as :doorkeeper_authorize! rendered or redirected
Completed 403 Forbidden in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

This was working fine with the previous version of doorkeeper. The tests broke when I upgraded the doorkeeper gem. What am I doing wrong? Or is there a new way of testing doorkeeper protected controllers?

**UPDATE**
Below is an actual test sample

```
    describe "POST create" do
        describe "with valid params" do
            it "creates a new AppCity" do
                expect {
                    post :create, {:app_city => valid_attributes, :v => "HEAD", :payload_type => "NODE", :access_token => token.token}, valid_session
                }.to change(AppCity, :count).by(1)
            end

            it "persists the AppCity" do
                post :create, {:app_city => valid_attributes, :v => "HEAD", :access_token => token.token}, valid_session
                response_body = JSON.parse(response.body, symbolize_names: true)
                expect(response_body[:id]).to be_present
            end

            it "returns a 201 status" do
                post :create, {:app_city => valid_attributes, :v => "HEAD", :access_token => token.token}, valid_session
                response.status.should eq(201)
            end
        end

        describe "with invalid params" do
            it "returns validation error message" do
                post :create, {:app_city => { "name" => "" }, :v => "HEAD", :access_token => token.token}, valid_session
                response_body = JSON.parse(response.body, symbolize_names: true)
                expect(response_body[:name]).to include "can't be blank"
            end

            it "returns a 422 status" do
                post :create, {:app_city => { "name" => "" }, :v => "HEAD", :access_token => token.token}, valid_session
                response.status.should eq(422)
            end
        end
    end
```

Comment: Don't you also need to apply the created token? Supply it in the request somehow? 

Can you perhaps supply a more complete test, with both setup and the actual test and payload?

Comment: @EmilKampp I have edited the question to include the actual test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem. I was getting a `403 Forbidden` because my I was sending a request with insufficient scope. I had defined the following scopes in doorkeeper.rb

```
# Define access token scopes for your provider
# For more information go to https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper/wiki/Using-Scopes
default_scopes  :public
optional_scopes :write, :update
```

For my specs to pass again I had to specify which actions required a specific access token scope e.g:

```
class Api::V1::ProductsController < Api::V1::ApiController
  before_action -> { doorkeeper_authorize! :public }, only: :index
  before_action only: [:create, :update, :destroy] do
    doorkeeper_authorize! :admin, :write
  end
end
```

I initially only had `before_action :doorkeeper_authorize!, except: [:index, :show]`. What I needed to do was define the `:write` and `:update` scopes on the `:create`, `:update` and `:destroy` actions. Or alternatively do away with the scopes completely.

I am also using CanCanCan so I guess the scopes should be redundant in my case.

[Further reading here](https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper/wiki/Using-Scopes)