# Doorkeeper not working after an upgrade from 1.4 to 4.0, not sure what to try next

Tags: ruby-on-rails, doorkeeper

I upgraded a rails app using Doorkeeper from rails 4.0 to 4.2 It also updated Doorkeeper to 4.0 from 1.4

The doorkeper app use Devise to authenticate user.

When allowing a client to use doorkeeper, the user is correctly redirected on the doorkeeper/provider app, and can log. User is immediately redirected on the third party app.

But when the Third Party app contact directly the API of the doorkeeper provider app, the answer is a 403 with the following error in the logs :

```
Filter chain halted as :doorkeeper_authorize! rendered or redirected
```

I tried to identify a problem by comparing the doorkeeper app with examples from doorkeeper but it seems it should work.

I have no idea what to do next to solve my problem.

EDIT: I followed panda advice and i added scopes to doorkeeper_authorize! :

```
before_action -> { doorkeeper_authorize! :public,:user,:admin }
```

Now everything works like in the previous version.

Comment: Looks like it is because of scopes. Please have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31787412/filter-chain-halted-as-doorkeeper-authorize-rendered-or-redirected

Comment: Upgrading major versions of any library should be done with great care, and with reading the changelog very carefully. Upgrading multiple major versions at once should generally not be done.

Answer (score 0):

I followed panda advice and i added scopes to doorkeeper_authorize! :

```
before_action -> { doorkeeper_authorize! :public,:user,:admin }
```

Now everything works like in the previous version.